# HAPROXY SSL handshake failure - debugging process?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

My HAPROXY 2.8.1 terminates SSL connections and does clear text with the backend servers.
When I test using my PC, there are no errors, however it fails when my customers' devices try to communicate. This means I had to rollback from using 2.8 and I am back at 1.8. I just would like to know how I can set everything/prepare myself to further debug this issue correctly in an easy manner so to be able to identify the culprit when I do a live session with them. I also tried adding httpslog to current HAPROXY 1.8 to check their devices successfull handshakes but haproxy didnt recognize this option.

Relevant haproxy.conf 2.8 parts:

```
global
  ...
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers   PROFILE=SYSTEM 
  ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

defaults
  ...
  log-format          "%ci %s %r %ST"

frontend frontend-https
    bind :443           ssl no-sslv3 crt /etc/haproxy/ssl
    mode                http
    option              httpslog
    ....
```

The error I get with the devices ("option httpslog" was unfortunately not set at that moment):

```
frontend-https/1: SSL handshake failure (error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol)
```

The successfull message I get when I test with my PC (using "option httpslog"):

```
frontend-https~ backend-web/API1 0/0/1/127/128 200 393 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "POST /script.php HTTP/1.1" 0/0000000000000000/0/0/0 <my-domain>/TLSv1.3/TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

The output for haproxy -vv is the following:

```
HAProxy version 2.8.1-a90123a 2023/07/03 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2028.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.8.1.html
Running on: Linux 4.18.0-477.15.1.el8_8.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 28 15:04:18 UTC 2023 x86_64
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = cc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfatal-errors -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference -fwrapv -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-string-plus-int -Wno-atomic-alignment
  OPTIONS = USE_LIBCRYPT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_PCRE=1
  DEBUG   = -DDEBUG_STRICT -DDEBUG_MEMORY_POOLS

Feature list : -51DEGREES +ACCEPT4 +BACKTRACE -CLOSEFROM +CPU_AFFINITY +CRYPT_H -DEVICEATLAS +DL -ENGINE +EPOLL -EVPORTS +GETADDRINFO -KQUEUE -LIBATOMIC +LIBCRYPT +LINUX_SPLICE +LINUX_TPROXY +LUA +MATH -MEMORY_PROFILING +NETFILTER +NS -OBSOLETE_LINKER +OPENSSL -OPENSSL_WOLFSSL -OT +PCRE -PCRE2 -PCRE2_JIT -PCRE_JIT +POLL +PRCTL -PROCCTL -PROMEX -PTHREAD_EMULATION -QUIC +RT +SHM_OPEN +SLZ +SSL -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +SYSTEMD +TFO +THREAD +THREAD_DUMP +TPROXY -WURFL -ZLIB

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_TGROUPS=16, MAX_THREADS=256, default=2).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.5
Built with network namespace support.
Built with libslz for stateless compression.
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built with PCRE version : 8.42 2018-03-20
Running on PCRE version : 8.42 2018-03-20
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with gcc compiler version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
         h2 : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H2    flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
       fcgi : mode=HTTP  side=BE     mux=FCGI  flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
  <default> : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H1    flags=HTX
         h1 : mode=HTTP  side=FE|BE  mux=H1    flags=HTX|NO_UPG
  <default> : mode=TCP   side=FE|BE  mux=PASS  flags=
       none : mode=TCP   side=FE|BE  mux=PASS  flags=NO_UPG

Available services : none

Available filters :
    [BWLIM] bwlim-in
    [BWLIM] bwlim-out
    [CACHE] cache
    [COMP] compression
    [FCGI] fcgi-app
    [SPOE] spoe
    [TRACE] trace
```

Further more, here is what I was able to gather using tlssled.sh. the followings are supported:

```
2.8 BOX
-------
Accepted  TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256        Curve 25519 DHE 253

Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384            
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-CCM                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256            
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-CCM                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA256                
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA256                
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits

1.8 BOX
-------
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384            
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA256                
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA              
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256            
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA256                
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA              
Accepted  TLSv1.2  ?? bits   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  ?? bits   TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA    
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  112 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA    
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA     
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5     

Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  AES256-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA              
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  AES128-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA              
Accepted  TLSv1.1  ?? bits   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  ?? bits   TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA    
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  112 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA    
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA     
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5     

Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  AES256-SHA                   
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  AES128-SHA
```

Comment: An error such as `tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol` appears to suggest that your HAproxy 2.8 is configured to mandate cryptographic ciphers and protocols that the client doesn't support. When you mentioned your clients devices, are that users and their laptops/PC's or actual devices? Because with the latter it is often much more likely that those haven't been updated to support modern crypto requirements.

Comment: Yes, that is what I suspect as well, their devices have probably lower cryptographic standards compared to what I have implemented into 2.8. I however don't know how to facilitate this debugging process and make sure that it can accept whatever they need to use. My plan is to make this config work using their accepted standards, and then later on plan a transition with them. Their devices are softwares located on their servers through some routers they have.

Comment: In addition AFAIK the line [`ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM`](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.8/configuration.html#ssl-default-bind-ciphers)  suggests  RHEL or a derivative configuration syntax that uses a crypto policy https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening  or similar approach. - Can you run `update-crypto-policies --show` and/or see what ciphers/protocols actually get set with `PROFILE=SYSTEM` ?

Comment: You can explicitly set all kinds of legacy and then log what the clients are actually willing/capable to negotiate

Comment: In the older version of haproxy you can log the SSL/TLS settings the clients use with the [`%sslc`](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-log-customization) option

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ran update-crypto-policies --show on the 2.8 box (rocky linux) and it only returns DEFAULT. This command however doesnt exist on the old 1.8 box (centos). When using "%ci\ %s\ %r\ %ST\ %sslv %sslc" on 1.8 it shows .....TLSv1 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA for their devices

Comment: How would one go at logging what their software is willing to negociate?

Comment: ...and does TLSv1 really represent TLS 1.0 in this case? That would make sense anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal by would manually enable some older tls versions and ciphers and see how it goes then. I usef Mozilla-security to generate this

```
global
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets

    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
    ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tls-tickets

    # openssl dhparam 1024 > /path/to/dhparam
    ssl-dh-param-file /path/to/dhparam

frontend ft_test
    mode    http
    bind    :443 ssl crt /path/to/<cert+privkey+intermediate> alpn h2,http/1.1
    bind    :80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

    # HSTS (63072000 seconds)
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000
```